# How to convert a recursive array into a string using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with nested arrays inside that I need to convert into a string with a given format.

This is for a PHP website. I get the information from a database, it comes as an array, and I need to pass it to charts.js so that I can plot it.

This is the varDump I get when I query the DB:

```
array(4) { [0]=> array(2) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2019-05-19 00:00:00" ["price"]=> string(3) "120" } [1]=> array(2) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2019-05-12 00:00:00" ["price"]=> string(3) "100" } [2]=> array(2) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2019-05-05 00:00:00" ["price"]=> string(3) "120" } [3]=> array(2) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2019-04-28 00:00:00" ["price"]=> string(3) "110" } }
```

This is what I would need as a result in a text string:

```
data: [{
    x: 2019-05-19 00:00:00,
    y: 120
}, {
    t: 2019-05-12 00:00:00,
    y: 100
}, {
    t: 2019-05-05 00:00:00,
    y: 120
}, {
    t: 2019-04-28 00:00:00,
    y: 110
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_map as below,

```
$temp = array_map(function ($item) {return array_combine(["x", "y"], $item); }, $temp);
```

I created `['x','y']` to combine as key as replacement for `$item`'s keys.

[array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) — Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values

[Working demo](https://3v4l.org/uW4lC).

Comment: Check now. I give explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the array and make a new one, and then `json_encode` it.

```
$data = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $data['x'] = $row['date'];
    $data['y'] = $row['price'];
}

json_encode($data);
```